# Is it possible to partly cover the element, but leave it visible to the cursor?

Tags: html, css, z-index

In the [template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arthurmiko/arthurmiko.github.io/master/shadows_portfolio/template/Portfolio_Website_Template%20copy.jpg), I need to implement overlay images on the menu, but I would like to leave with the menu items available to a clique completely, not partially.

Now it implemented so that only the upper part of button is available https://arthurmiko.github.io/shadows_portfolio/

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #777;
  transition: .3s;
}

.elem:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f77;
}

.higher-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 308px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .9);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-box">
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
</div>
<div class="higher-box"></div>
```

Is it possible to somehow leave the gray blocks are available for the cursor, in the overlapping area of blue block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove the cursor actions for `higher-box` you can do it with `.higher-box { pointer-events: none }`

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #777;
  transition: .3s;
}

.elem:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f77;
}

.higher-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 308px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .9);
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-box">
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="elem"></div></a>
</div>
<div class="higher-box"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudoelement, assuming there is no previous stacking context:

**HTML**

```
<div class="covered"></div>
<div class="covering"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.covered{
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.covered:hover{
  background-color: green;
}

.covering{
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}

.covered:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 300;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KryBBr